# What module would give an image thumbnail list in a slider format?

Tags: 7, views, javascript

Which module would give the following slider effect? So i have a list of image thumbnails and I want to be able to scroll through them by clicking on the left or right arrows and have it show X number of them depending on my screen size.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [jCarousel](https://drupal.org/project/jcarousel) for views: --- its a bit outdated so you need the updated patch.

**You have to apply the following patch: https://drupal.org/node/1548484#comment-8260283 to make it responsive.**

If you have a better solution. Do let us know! :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Juicebox HTML5 Responsive Image Galleries](https://www.drupal.org/project/juicebox) Module of drupal.

This module provides an integration between the popular Juicebox HTML5 responsive gallery library and Drupal. Juicebox is in many ways the successor of Simpleviewer and offers a powerful cross-device solution for image galleries, sliders and more.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [jcarousel](https://drupal.org/project/jcarousel) .

This module allows developers and themers to make use of the jCarousel jQuery plugin. It includes a developer API that other modules can use, as well as Views integration so that you can turn any list of content or images into a carousel.

You can also try the [views slideshow](https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) but this would need some extra javascript code.

Comment: views_slideshow only lets you display one image at a time.

Comment: @duckx you can do it with slideshow

Comment: @bala slideshow only displays one element at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bxslider views slideshow](https://drupal.org/project/bxslider_views_slideshow) module to achieve slideshow functionality.

> This module provides integration with bxSlider

There is a bug in `views slideshow` module that if you select `Left Scroll` as slide option, then it will only slide in only one direction (`Left`) wheather you click on `right` or `left` arrow.

You can also use [jCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel) Module suggested by @sokratis in his answer.

Comment: bxslider is nice, but seems to only show one element at a time.